# Is Paypal REST API direct card payment allowed for Indian merchant from out side Indian border? If yes than which currency allowed?

Tags: php, rest, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

I have Created demo using **PAYPAL REST API** to collect payment in India with currency as USD from outside India.

In which set payment_method equals paypal_payment. During the payment processing user leave my website and go to PayPal payment page.

In PayPal payment page the user can pay using the card or his/her PayPal account. When I have tried with card payment, PAYPAL shows a screen with "**back to merchant**" button.

I can not get: what is the issue to do payment? why does PayPal not allow the card payment?

Comment: This is [documented](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#international-developer-questions) by Paypal in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal card payment using REST API is available only for US and UK merchant account. 
[Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/currency-codes/#direct-credit-card-payments)

Comment: I have the contact at Paypal support. it's fine.